# Column limit in H2O data frame?

Tags: r, apache-spark, h2o

I am working with a data set in R which contains 42,457 rows and 785 columns.  The first column is a binary response variable (called `label`) and the remaining columns are binary features.

I tried to fit a logistic regression model using `rsparkling`  (described [here](http://spark.rstudio.com/h2o.html)) but got errors.  I traced this to a step that converts a Spark version of this table to an H2O data frame.

Here's the function I'm using for testing.  The Spark instance `sc` is up and running and `df` is the raw data set as a standard R data frame:

```
load_h2o <- function(df, rows = nrow(df), cols = ncol(df)) {
        df <- df[1:rows, 1:cols]
        copy_to(sc, df, "df", overwrite = TRUE)
        df_tbl <- tbl(sc, "df")
        h2o_tbl <- as_h2o_frame(sc, df_tbl, strict_version_check=FALSE)
        return(h2o_tbl)
}
```

The head of `df$label` is `1 1 1 0 0 0`.  However if I load the full data set, i.e. `load_h2o(raw_data)` the head of the resulting `label` column is `0 0 0 0 0 0`; in fact all values in the H2O data frame are 0.  If I restrict the number of columns to 200 (i.e. `load_h2o(raw_data, cols = 200)`), then the resulting H2O data frame contains all the data as expected.  If `cols = 201`, we're back to all zeros.

Finally, if I load the data set directly from disk with `h2o::h2o.importFile`, then the full data set comes through with no problem and I'm able to fit the logistic regression.  However I'd like to be able to load it from an R data frame in order to distribute the object within a package.

Is there a limit on the maximum number of columns for this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

We're using Spark 1.6.2 and I believe this is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16664).

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit column limit in H2O (certainly not at 785, which is not big).  Spark 1.6 is very old now, I recommend moving forward.

See if what you're seeing might be related to this problem:

https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3808

If so, one workaround that was discovered was to .cache() the dataframe in Spark before passing it to H2O.